# View list of addresses in order in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

I have some addresses that I want to visit, and I want to draw the order I should take in Google Maps.

Is there any feature that enables me to do this?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to find the optimal route between the addresses, or just a way to view a predefined route?

Answer (score 2):

The ability to have multiple destinations for directions has been available in the "new" Google Maps since about October, 2013.

From [Map Help](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3092446)

> Here's how to get directions with multiple destinations or waypoints:
>
> 1. Get directions [as you would normally].
> 2. Click the **+** button in the info card at the top of the map.
> 3. In the text box that appears, type a destination. You can also click the location on the map.
> 4. To add another destination, click **+** again.
>
> To remove a destination, hover
> over the location in the card and click the X that appears to the
> right of the address. To adjust the order of your destinations, click
> and drag the circles to the left of the destination names.
>
> Note: Multiple destinations are not available for public transit
> directions or flight searches.

[image: info card screen shot]